# How to create a matrix of multi-cells group from a list of data

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of data of dynamic number of records in **Google Sheets** and a custom function that produce a sparkline graph from time series data (such as 30 days sales records of an item) stored on other sheets not shown.

I would like to create a matrix of standard snippet of information (cell E1 to G6) showing a product's basic info with the respective sparkline graph stored in a group of merged cells (eg. 5 rows and 3 columns) so the graph is big enough to be read. I need to have to graph stored in a merged cells because the real life sheets contain other information.

I am trying to come up with a super formula (in cell E1 in the picture) that generates this matrix so I don't need to copy a group of cells (the snippet) with formulas to a number of rows. I have tried using a combo of Makearray(), map(), lambda(), vstack() and hstack() but just cannot come up with a single formula that works.

Wonder if there is any creative and advance way of achieving this objective! Thanks.

This is an example of what I like to achieve: [google sheets example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c58wpeMX6LbWjcG5-eEpvdDGEVs2cu-CNRPDF8pVdZ8/edit#gid=0)
[image]

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response.

Comment: Thanks. Here is the link: [google sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c58wpeMX6LbWjcG5-eEpvdDGEVs2cu-CNRPDF8pVdZ8/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,tocol(data!A2:A,1),
       stat,wraprows(reduce(tocol(,1),Σ,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,c,ITEM_PRICE(c),ITEM_QTY(c)))),9,),
       spark,wraprows(reduce(tocol(,1),Σ,lambda(a,c,vstack(a,RECENT_SALES(c),,))),9,),
       reduce(tocol(,1),sequence(rows(stat)),lambda(a,c,ifna(vstack(a,index(stat,c),index(spark,c),,,,)))))
```

[image]